# Where is Apache download directory?

Tags: apache

I want to download Apache. The website apache.org redirected me to this page (mirror) http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/apache/ At that page there are a lot of folders none of them is called Apache, and this fact is confusing for me. What should I download out of that bunch of folders?

Comment: Thanks to all users who have responded! That time I was so stupid, that didn't know that Apache is the name of the organization, and that webserver httpd has a separate name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re probably confused because you want to download the Apache Webserver (httpd). Apache is a software foundation though which does a lot more things than just the webserver.

That being said, you can download Apache httpd here: http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the binaries or the source code?

If you know what you're doing Im guessing the correct directory is here:

http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/apache/httpd/

Apache has tonnes of projects so theres a bunch of folders for each.

Let us know what OS you are using because there is probably an easy way integrated into your OS for example debian or ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Answer (score 0):

The Apache HTTP server? Or some other Apache project? You can see a list of all their projects at this page, near the bottom - http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi

Click on the project name and it will take you to that project with a more direct download link.